# Syntax for range parameter, recognized in VBA, not in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a formula to use in a cell to run a calculation on columns of data depending on what it sees below the column heads (the ranges used as parameters).  The code runs in vba, but returns #VALUE! in cell.  My problem boils down to using the wrong syntax in cell to pass ranges to the function.

The Function is

```
Function MultiComp(Date1 As Range, Delta1 As Range, Date2 As Range, Delta2 As Range) 
  'Do Stuff
  'Return answer as a double or "Insufficient" if no data is available
End Function
```

and is running in VBA when called by another function in line:

```
Range("K25") = MultiComp(Range("B4"), Range("F4"), Range("M4"), Range("Q4"))
```

but shows #VALUE! in cell when using:

```
"=MultiComp(B4, F4, M4, Q4)"
```

This should be a relatively simple syntax fix, but for the life of me I can't pin it down.

I've tried variations of Range(B4), Range("B4"), B4:B4, an attempt to use indirect and the code below as a controlled example, which behaved as expected to "=RangeTest(J20)" in a cell.

```
Function RangeTest(Here As Range)
   MsgBox (Here.Address & " is range Address" & vbNewLine & Here & " is range Value") 
End Function
```

EDIT: Full Code is

```
Function MultiComp(Date1 As Range, Delta1 As Range, Date2 As Range, Delta2 As Range)
Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim V1w, V2w As Variant
Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestingPage")

A = FindRecentDates(Date1)
V1 = wsf.Transpose(RangeFromTop(Delta1, A).Value)
ReDim V1w(1 To UBound(V1))
For i = 1 To UBound(V1w)
    V1w(i) = ws.Range("A1") - (wsf.Days(Now(), Date1.Offset(i - 1, 0)))
Next i
V1SumP = wsf.SumProduct(V1, V1w)
V1Weight = wsf.Sum(V1w)
TotalSumP = TotalSumP + V1SumP
TotalWeight = TotalWeight + V1Weight

B = FindRecentDates(Date2)
V2 = wsf.Transpose(RangeFromTop(Delta2, B).Value)
ReDim V2w(1 To UBound(V2))
For i = 1 To UBound(V2w)
    V2w(i) = ws.Range("A1") - (wsf.Days(Now(), Date2.Offset(i - 1, 0)))
Next i
V2SumP = wsf.SumProduct(V2, V2w)
V2Weight = wsf.Sum(V2w)
TotalSumP = TotalSumP + V2SumP
TotalWeight = TotalWeight + V2Weight

'/Calculating Average/
If TotalWeight = 0 Then TotalWeight = 1
WeightedDelta = (TotalSumP / TotalWeight) '/ Denominator
MultiComp = UndoDelta(WeightedDelta)
If TotalSumP = 0 Then MultiComp = "Calculating"

End Function
```

Which itself is calling additional functions, I'm not entirely sure this will be enough to work with then.

Comment: you will need to post the rest of the code.  something is causing an error and as such when called from the worksheet it short-circuits and returns the error.

Comment: I second the above comment. Also, add `Debug.Print Date1.Address` etc in your function and examine the output

Comment: Just so you know, there are many things you can do with a function called from vba that you cannot do with a function called from the work sheet, which is probably why it works with vba but not called from the sheet.  Without seeing the code we cannot help.

Comment: If your function is trying to write to any cell, using it as a UDF will always yield a `#VALUE` error. Functions take input, compute an output, issue it to the caller... ideally without any side-effects.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid hard coding values, but for the sake of time I think I may just have to proceed without the cells holding the function. 
Thank you all for your advice.